# Can I convert an IFeature to ILayer and add it to the map?

Tags: arcobjects, feature-layer, feature-class

I want to use `FeatureClass.Search()` to get a specific Feature and I want to convert this one to `ILayer` and set it to the Map, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would potentially approach this with the iFeatureLayerDefinition interface.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0012/0012000004v2000000.htm

It has a CreateSelectionLayer function which:

> Creates a new feature layer from the existing layer based on the
>   current selection and the specified query expression.